# I try to write voice content to external file it work good but if I record for 1 minute or 20 seconds the size of file is 64 byte why

Tags: flutter, dart

> " i use flutte sound package "
> "saveFile function get the path of file and the fileName and save it to external file "

```
Future<bool> saveFile(Uint8List url,String fileName) async {

Directory? directory;
directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
///   print("direcory ===>"+directory.path.toString());
try {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {

    directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (await _requstPermission(Permission.storage) &&
        await _requstPermission(Permission.accessMediaLocation) &&
        await _requstPermission(Permission.manageExternalStorage)) {
      String newPath = "";
      List<String> folders = directory!.path.split("/");
      for (int i = 1; i < folders.length; i++) {
        String folder = folders[i];
        if (folder != "Android") {
          newPath += "/" + folder;
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }
      newPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/SpaChat2/";
      directory = Directory(newPath);
      //print(directory.path);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {

  }
  if (!await directory.exists()) {
    await directory.create(recursive: true);
  }
  if (await directory.exists()) {
    File audioFile =  File(
        directory.path +fileName.split("/").last);



    print("//////////////////////////////////////////////");
    // print(bytes);
    print("url =============================================="+utf8.decode(url));

    await audioFile.writeAsBytes(url);

    return true;
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
return false;
```

}

> " _requstPermission get permission for access device resource "

```
Future<bool> _requstPermission(Permission permission) async {
  if (await permission.isGranted) {
    return true;
  } else {
    var res = await permission.request();
    if (res == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

> " starting record voice"

```
void startRecord() async {
  try {
    _myRecorder.stopRecorder();
  } catch (e) {}
  currentDuration.value = Duration.zero;
  try {
    bool hasStorage = await _requstPermission(Permission.storage);
    bool hasMic = await _requstPermission( Permission.microphone);

    if (!hasStorage || !hasMic) {
      if (!hasStorage) await _requstPermission(Permission.storage);
      if (!hasMic) await  _requstPermission( Permission.microphone);
      print('[chat_composer]  Denied permissions');
      return;
    }
    if (onRecordStart != null) onRecordStart!();

    Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = dir.path +
        '/' +
        DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() +
        '.aac';
  pathToSaveAudio=path;
    await _myRecorder.startRecorder(
      toFile: pathToSaveAudio,
      //codec: Codec.aacADTS,
    );

    emit(RecordAudioStarted());
  } catch (e) {
    emit(RecordAudioReady());
  }
}
```

> " stopRecord functon stop recording after stop record voice it call saveFile function and add the path of voice to saveFile arguments "

```
void stopRecord() async {
   // timer.cancel();
   try {
     String? result = await _myRecorder.stopRecorder();

     if (result != null) {
      // tempPath =result;
       print('[chat_composer]  Audio path:  "$result');



       onRecordEnd(result);
       Uint8List bytes = Utf8Encoder().convert(pathToSaveAudio);
       saveFile(bytes,pathToSaveAudio);
     }
   } finally {
     currentDuration.value = Duration.zero;
   }
   emit(RecordAudioReady());
 }
```

Comment: Does the file still play the recorded audio if the recorded length is greater than 1 min 20s

Comment: yes  , I want to know how much the size of file

Comment: I need to write content of voice the voice that i recorded into file note the path of temp file